# Setting TIME field to NULL with Zend_Db

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

I came across what looks like an odd issue with either `Zend_Db` or PHP's PDO MySQL driver, that perhaps stems from my lack of knowledge of those two.

Let's assume I have a MySQL Table with a `NULL`able `TIME` field. If I run a query like this in MySQL client:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytime = NULL WHERE id = 1;
```

Everything works as expected and *mytime* field will hold `NULL` as value after this query.

However, if I run the exact same query in PHP through the `Zend_Db_Adapter`, the *mytime* field is set to `'0:0:0'` after such query:

```
$db->getConnection()->exec('UPDATE mytable SET mytime = NULL WHERE id = 1');
```

How do I set that TIME field to NULL?

I'm using PHP5.3 with PDO MySQL driver, Zend Framework 1.11 and MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, i.e.:

```
$db->getConnection()->exec('UPDATE mytable SET mytime = NULL WHERE id = 1');
```

That should work. I tested it.

### Caveat

If the data type **time** is `NOT NULL`, then trying to set it to `NULL` will cause the value `NULL` to be defaulted to `00:00:00`, which may be unexpected behaviour e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `time` datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Trying to insert or update the time field above with `NULL` will cause the value `00:00:00` to be inserted.

This is similar for date, datetime, and a few other data types. e.g. Trying to set a data type **datetime** which is `NOT NULL` **to** `NULL` will default its value to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

*NOTE: Mysql will not throw an error when you try to set a `NULL` value to a `NUT NULL` data type, you can change this behaviour by setting MySQL's `SQL_MODE` to `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`: see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090293/best-practice-mysql-configuration-in-development).*

### The Fix

Change the field to allow `NULL` and it should be fine:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Now the time field can be set to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

use `new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')` instead of NULL :

```
$zend_null = new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL');
$db->getConnection()->exec("UPDATE mytable SET mytime = $zend_null WHERE id = 1");
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($zend_null)` display? And why do you write `$zend_null` literally into the exec string parameter (and not with substitution - an error?)?

Comment: @hakre my mistake it should be between double quotes not single quote , var_dump($zend_null) will print an object (an instance of Zend_Db_Expr)

Comment: What will print `var_dump((string) $zend_null);`?

Comment: i guess just NULL because  Zend_Db_Expr's __toString method just returns the expression given tp it's constructor

Comment: Oh well, which leads to what the TS already does. Your answer looks superfluous.